# My controller is receiving a route parameter when he souldnt

Tags: symfony, parameters, routes

I have a strange problem that occur only in my production server.

When I get into /1/config, $post_type that should be null receive an Entity.

The other route /1/config/1 work fine

```
/**
 * Config a post entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/config", name="post_config")
 * @Route("/{id}/config/{post_type}", name="post_config_type")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function configAction(Request $request, Post $post, PostType $post_type = null)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $post_type_list = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:PostType')->findBy(array('enabled' => true));

    if (!is_null($post_type)){

        // code
    }
    // more code
}
```

I really can't find the problem, maybe a server configuration issue.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found the problem

Parameters in route must be named exactly as it is received as parameter in the action.

```
/**
 * Config a post entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{post}/config", name="post_config")
 * @Route("/{post}/config/{post_type}", name="post_config_type")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function configAction(Request $request, Post $post, PostType $post_type = null)
```